# Django: help in implementing error reporting

Tags: django, error-handling, slack

I am trying to implement an error reporting system that directly sends the errors to slack.
The steps are like this:

1. My API fails and return a 400 error.
2. The Middleware will check if the response code equals 400
3. Call the function to send the error message to slack.

API:

```
class SomeWorkingAPI(APIView):
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

    def get(self, request):
        client = request.query_params.get('client', None)
            try:
                #do something
            except:
                error_msg = "error occurred in the API"
                return Response({'message': error_msg}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        return Response(result, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Middleware:

```
def error_reporting(request, error_msg=None):
    # this is the function that sends the message to my slack channel
    return 'error reported successfully'

class SomeMiddleWare(object):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response

    def process_template_response(self, request, response):
        if response.status_code >= 400:
            error_reporting(request, error_msg=response['message'])
```

The help I need:

1. I want to send the error message returned from the API (`return Response({'message': error_msg}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)`) to the middleware. How can i achieve that? What i'm doing in middleware (`response['message']`), is throwing KeyError.
2. Since the middleware has both request and response, it would be great if I can get all the query params and payload from the request. When I'm using `request.query_params` in the `error_reporting` function, I'm getting `AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'query_params'`.
3. It would be great if you can provide some other way to achieve my goal.
   Thank you